# docker can't see the files

Tags: docker, nginx, dockerfile

I am dealing with docker and nginx. Trying to raise a simple server with a static html page. It is not working, when building the container writes: `COPY failed: "file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat index.html: file does not exist"`
The content of the Dockerfile is shown below, I assume that the problem is that the docker cannot see files outside its directory. How can this be fixed?

```
FROM nginx:mainline
CMD ls; touch index.html; echo "\n"; ls; echo "<html>Hello, World!</html>" > index.html;
COPY index.html usr/share/nginx/html
```

The file is created, everything is written into it (I checked with cat), but the docker does not want to see it. I did everything according to the documentation, but for some reason it does not work

nginx doc from dockerhub

[image: 1]

Comment: Looks like you used `CMD` instead of `RUN`.

Comment: And you did not understand what `COPY` does. Reading the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) should be your 1st solution before posting on SO.

Comment: Rewritten, still "file does not exist"

Comment: Yes, obviously, because `COPY` copies from the build context to the image layer (as explained in the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy)), it is not a useless alias for the `cp` command.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple errors in your Dockerfile:

- [CMD](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) is not used to run commands but to specify a default command for a container. You should use [RUN](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run) instead.
- [COPY](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) is used to copy files from the [build context](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/context/) to the container filesystem. Use the `cp` command in a `RUN` instruction to move a file, or use [WORKDIR](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir) to define the current working directory.

This should be working:

```
FROM nginx:mainline

WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html

RUN echo "<html>Hello, World!</html>" > index.html
```

If you are using [BuildKit](https://docs.docker.com/build/buildkit/) you can use alternatives to write your file using a [Dockerfile frontend](https://docs.docker.com/build/buildkit/dockerfile-frontend/#dockerfile-frontend) and [here-documents](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#here-documents):

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1.4
FROM nginx:mainline

RUN <<INDEX cat > index.html
<html>Hello, World!</html>
INDEX

# or

COPY <<-EOT /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html
<html>Hello, World!</html>
EOT
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I will read more documentation:)